# How redirect simple products of Configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product

How to redirect a simple product's page to the parent configurable product page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the code below should work only if the simple products are assigned to only one configurable product.
by default, magento allows you to add a simple product to as many configurable products you need.

Let's create a module and call it `StackExchange_Redirect`.
You will need the following files.

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Redirect.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Redirect>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </StackExchange_Redirect>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Redirect/etc/config.xml` - the module configuration file where you declare an observer for the product view page

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Redirect>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Redirect>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <stackexchange_redirect>
                <class>StackExchange_Redirect_Model</class>
            </stackexchange_redirect>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <stackexchange_redirect>
                        <class>stackexchange_redirect/observer</class>
                        <method>redirectToConfigurable</method>
                    </stackexchange_redirect>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Redirect/Model/Observer.php` - the observer that should redirect to the configurable product page.

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_Redirect_Model_Observer
{
    public function redirectToConfigurable($observer)
    {
        $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $configurableParentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getParentIdsByChild($id);
        if (isset($configurableParentIds[0])) {
            $mainProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($configurableParentIds[0]);
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($mainProduct->getProductUrl(), 301);
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

when you are done, clear the cache.

Comment: Where do I put this code?

Comment: I've edited the answer and provided a full module that should work.

Comment: It returns the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting '{' /Model/Observer.php on line 4

Comment: sorry, I missed a bracket. You could have spotted this :).

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error

Comment: get the code again for the Observer.php file. I added the missing bracket

Comment: @Marius I want to redirect to the configurable and add the parameter ?sel={simpleproductid}  - Is there a simple modification that could achieve this?

Comment: @Marius is this a standard customization to redirect a simple product page to configurable? means is this not impact SEO or performance?

Just wanted to list down limitation once we implement this in M2, please help me on this.
Waiting for your positive reply!

Comment: I have no idea how it affects SEO. i just wrote down how it can be done in case someone decides to do it.